# Print the maximum border of the shapes

Tags: spectre.css

You are given a table with
n rows and
m columns. Each cell is colored with white or black. Considering the shapes created by black cells, what is the maximum border of these shapes? Border of a shape means the maximum number of consecutive black cells in any row or column without any white cell in between.

A shape is a set of connected cells. Two cells are connected if they share an edge. Note that no shape has a hole in it.

The first line contains
t denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case contains integers
n sand m denoting the number of rows and columns of the matrix. Here, '#' represents a black cell and '.' represents a white cell.
Each of the next
lines contains
integers.